# Change drupal search result count

Tags: 7, theming, hooks, search, paging

Drupal search is giving 10 items per page. The number is hard coded in search core module. Is there any way to make it 15?. I am using drupal 6.

Answer (score 1):

The [search configuration](http://drupal.org/project/search_config) module (version 7.x-1.1-beta1 or above) allows you to do that, among other things.

Comment: But i am using drupal 6